# Se repite código al hacer click en boton

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener

Cuando se ejecuta la funcion "pVolcados" genera un boton o varios con con un onclick asignado que al pulsar llama a otra funcion botonVolcado(). EL problema que lo que hay dentro de  `botones.click(function() {` La primera vez no lo ejecuta y la segunda vez lo ejecuta dos veces, la tercera vez lo ejecuta tres veces y asi sucesivamente. Creo que el click se me va sumando pero no se como hacer que no pase. No me da ningún error y el resultado de las funciones es correcto. He provado `e.stopPropagation();` pero no funciona

```
function pVolcados(){ //Funcion que me da los puntos de volcado
        html="";
        $.ajax({ /
            url: "php/pVolcado.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            objJsonV = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(objJsonV, function (i, item) {
                     html+="  <button type='button'  onclick='botonPvolcado();'   class='btn btn-light'>"+ objJsonV[i].name +"</button>";
                });
                $(volcado).append(html);
            }
        });
    }

function botonPvolcado(){ //FUncion repetida.
        var botones = $("#volcado button");
        botones.click(function() {
            botones.removeClass('activ');
            $(this).addClass('activ');
         });
    }
```

Comment: en el primer click ejecuta la funcion volcado con `onclick` y con el segundo el evento jquery!, fuera de que no veo que utilizes tu variable html para nada solo agregar contendio pero hasta hay no lo aplicas! la solucion mas simple es  `onclick='botonPvolcado(this);'`  y `function botonPvolcado(el){` aqui le estas pasando el elemento clicleado unicamente! no es necesario hacer otro click o opcion 2. `$(document).on("click","#volcado button",function() {`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, La variable html la uso a continuación aunque para el ejemplo quite bastante código para que fuera mas claro y .... se ve raro. Te importaría poner el código como respuesta?  Así puedo votar tu respuesta Gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿El código qué has escrito es exactamente el mismo que el que estás utilizando?
Si es así, comprueba que tienes bien puesto type='button' ya que en este código falta la comilla simple que cierra el tipo. Con esa correción he estado probando y funciona correctamente

Comment: Correcto, ya lo he corregido, algunas veces edito el código para evitar que se muestren partes que no interesan y me pasa esto. Tendré mas cuidado. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

si ya en la creacion del boton le asignas el handler(botonPvolcado) al evento de click para el boton, por que en el handler vuelves e invocas manualmente el handler de nuevo con la funcion click.

supongo que lo correcto seria:

```
function botonPvolcado(){ //FUncion repetida.
       let botones = $("#volcado button");
       botones.removeClass('activ');
       $(this).addClass('activ');

    }
```

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta. Por que no tengo mucha idea por no decir nada. Gracias a vosotros voy aprendiendo. El compañero Bryro me dio una gran pista y lo solucioné, me gustaría que pusiera el comentario en forma de respuesta para votarla positivamente.

Comment: te entiendo, estamos para ayudarnos.

Answer (score 1):

si no te interesa guardar los volcados anteriores puedes limpiar el html y solo
agregar los elementos de cada llamada
en html supon que tienes un div

```
<div id="seccionVolcados"></div>
```

en tu funcion success:

```
 $.each(objJsonV, function (i, item) {
                     html+="  <button type='button'  onclick='botonPvolcado();'   class='btn btn-light'>"+ objJsonV[i].name +"</button>";
                });

 $("#seccionVolcados").html("");//limpias la seccion
     $("#seccionVolcados").html(html);//agregas nuevos elementos
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a los compañeros he ido modificando un poco el código hasta que así me funciona correctamente.

```
function pVolcados(volcadoActivo){ 
        html="";
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "php/pVolcado.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
            objJsonV = JSON.parse(data);
                $(volcado).html("");
                $.each(objJsonV, function (i, item) {
                     html+="  <button type='button' onclick='botonPvolcado(this); ctrEntradaAlmacen("+objJsonV[i].id+",1); '   class='btn btn-light' >"+ objJsonV[i].name +"</button>";
                });
                $(volcado).html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    function botonPvolcado(boton){ 
        var botones = $("#volcado button"); 
        botones.removeClass('active');
        $(boton).addClass('active');
    }
```